# OfficeRuntime.auth.getAccessToken hanging after recent update

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

Has anyone else seen the `OfficeRuntime.auth.getAccessToken` hang after the recent update?

Our Outlook add-in running on the desktop used to get a token when used in the OnCompose event. Last week we noticed that the token was no longer being returned and the call to `getAccessToken`, neither returned nor reported an error.

Comment: That looks like a possible bug. If you don't get a response here in 24 hours, try creating an issue on the [office-js](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/new/choose) repo.

Comment: What version of Outlook and Windows are you on? Does calling `OfficeRuntime.auth.getAccessToken` hang when using another add-in, like ScriptLab?  (Scriplab is an add-in for Outlook, which is available in the store.)

Comment: I should have said, when the Taskpane is running on Desktop or the add-in is running on web, the call returns.

Comment: Versions
Windows 10 Enterprise 20H2
Microsoft® Outlook® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2110 Build 16.0.14524.20000) 64-bit

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "when the taskpane is running"?  Can you provide the steps you are taking to see this hang, including a code snippet?

Comment: When the add-in runs in the O365 web environment. No issues are all, in Outlook Desktop, opening the Task Pane from the ribbon, no problem. When composing a new email, the event fires and we go into the code below.

async function onMessageComposeHandler(event) {
    try {
        const token = await OfficeRuntime.auth.getAccessToken({ allowConsentPrompt: false, allowSignInPrompt: false });
        debugMessage('Success'};
    } catch (error) {
        debugMessage('Token Error');
    }
    debugMessage("End");
    event.completed();
}

Comment: Are you using [LaunchEvents/event-based](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/autolaunch) to run on OnNewMessageCompose?

Comment: Yes, we are. It was working on the Desktop and works fine for the Web and the Task pane on both. Granted two different runtime environments.

Comment: Are you saying OfficeRuntime.auth.getAccessToken was working fine for an Event-Based add-in in Desktop Outlook? That's surprising because it is one of the APIs that we have listed as blocked. See this link : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/autolaunch#event-based-activation-behavior-and-limitations. We recently un-blocked this API, however, the changes haven't rolled out yet. We are working to update our documentation to clarify support for this API, so you should see an update very soon.

Comment: It was. We were ones that requested it for our web version of the Add-in and one the signature endpoints were release and it all worked and we rolled it out to customers. When we fired up the add-in in the desktop to connect the event-based activation, it seem to be happy.

Comment: For Event-Based Add-ins for the Desktop Outlook client, OfficeRuntime.auth.getAccessToken was recently hooked up. So, it is highly unlikely that it worked for you unless you tried in the web client only, or used an add-in in the Desktop client that was not an Event-Based Add-ins extension point. Anyway, we are rolling out the fixes for this API for Event-Based Add-ins in the Desktop Outlook, so you should have it soon, and we have upcoming documentation with instructions on how to get it to work.

Comment: The documentation for enabling single sign-on (SSO) in Outlook add-ins that use event-based activation has been published and can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/use-sso-in-event-based-activation